# How to fix this error trying to set a profile picture?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, datepicker

Im trying to take a picture set it as profilepicture. But im getting this error :

```
A value of type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.
```

this are the methods thats involved.

```
_loadPicker(ImageSource source)async{
    File picked = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: source);
    if(picked!=null){
      setState(() {
        _pickedImage =picked  ;
      });
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

```
  CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 70,
                  child:_pickedImage ==null ?Text("Picture"):null,
                backgroundImage: _pickedImage!=null?FileImage(_pickedImage):null,
                                          ),
```

```
File _pickedImage;
```

Hope aynone can help and know how to fix this.

```
 void _showPickOptionsDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context)=>AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min ,
        children: <Widget>
      [ListTile(title:Text
          ("Pick from Gallery"),
      onTap:(){
           _loadPicker(ImageSource.gallery);
      },
      ),
        ListTile(title: Text("Take a picture"),
        onTap: (){
          _loadPicker(ImageSource.camera);
        }
        ,)
      ],
      ),
    ),);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

picked is type of PickedFile and not File. So you have to transform it like this:

```
File _pickedImage = File(picked.path)
```

So your code should be:

```
_loadPicker(ImageSource source)async{
PickedFile picked = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
if(picked!=null){
  setState(() {
    _pickedImage = File(picked.path)  ;
  });
}
Navigator.pop(context);
```

}

Comment: Im sorry I wanna use File picked = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: source); instance of PickedFile picked = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: source);  Im getting a error that says Undefined Name picked when I try your solution and also the old error is there

Comment: You have to use "PickedFile picked = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: source)" and after that "_pickedImage = File(picked.path)". I will edit my answer

Comment: ok no error anymore but it dont load the image My console says that:D/MediaScannerConnection(22569): Scanned /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MYAOO.com/files/Pictures/29b1f44d-039f-4336-99b3-ed682ed665c64205806533730892289.jpg to null.    So it dont update the image

Comment: Maybe you have to define a source like "source: ImageSource.camera". I will edit my answer

Comment: It don't work .The console still says the same

Comment: What is your code to upload the new image?

Comment: I updated my code there just the showPickoptions method . To upload the image im using load picker. But I think I got something my console says as a warning  this :
    The member 'platform' can only be used within 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart' or a test.

Comment: your code looks now right. I don't know the reason for your actual error. If I helped you, give me a vote

Comment: Yep thanks I will open a new question for that.